# Why bounty option is not showing for this question, it's approx 15 days old?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Why bounty option is not showing for this question, it's approx 15 days old?

[How to embed youtube videos in webpage for mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371441/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-webpage-for-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 8):

You have an outstanding bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580447/jquery-mobile-multiple-page-in-a-single-page-method-multiple-h1-effect-seo-acc), and you're only allowed to offer [one bounty at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067). For future reference, you can now check the status of your bounties by visiting the bounty tab in your profile. In your case, you can [find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84201/jitendra-vyas?tab=bounties).

Answer (score 6):

You [have a bounty active currently](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84201/jitendra-vyas?tab=bounties). You can only have one bounty active at any one time. When that is over, you'll be able to post a bounty on that question.